# Direct proof sequence of n length

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof

We denote a(n) as the number of sequence of n values of 0,1 and 2 where the value 0 can't be next to another 0 in the sequence.
For example, we can have (0,1,0,2), but not (0,0,2,1)

Prove by direct proof that a(n) = 2a(n-1) + 2a(n-2) for n ≥ 3

Comment: Do you mean to say that a(n) is the number of such sequences, rather than a particular sequence?

Comment: Are you sure? If a(n) is a sequence, what does a(n) = 2a(n-1) + 2a(n-2) mean?

Comment: correct you had it right for example a(3) is the number of such sequence of length 3 and 2a(3-1) + 2a(3-2) means if we sum the double of the number of such sequence of length 2 with the double of the number of such sequence of length 1 we obtain the number of such sequence of length 3

Comment: Yes, so `a(n)` is the number of such sequences, and not a sequence itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct any such sequence of length `n` (for `n>2`) uniquely in one of these four ways:

```
s(n-1), 1
s(n-1), 2
s(n-2), 1, 0
s(n-2), 2, 0
```

Where `s(n-1)` is any such sequence of length `n-1` and `s(n-2)` is any such sequence of length `n-2`.

Or to put it in words; a sequence of length `n` (for `n>2`) can be any sequence of length `n-1` followed by a `1` or a `2`, or any sequence of length `n-2` followed by `1, 0` or `2, 0`.

If `a(n)` is the number of such sequences of length `n`, this observation immediately gives that `a(n) = 2a(n-1) + 2a(n-2)` as required.

And for completeness, `a(1) = 3` and `a(2) = 8`.